# How do I draw an arrow between two points in d3v4?

Tags: javascript, geometry, d3.js

I have created a custom path renderer that draws an arrow between the nodes in my d3 graph as shown in the snippet. I have one last issue I am getting stuck on,

How would I rotate the arrow portion so that it is pointing from the direction of the curve instead of the direction of the source?

```js
var w2 = 6,
  ar2 = w2 * 2,
  ah = w2 * 3,
  baseHeight = 30;

// Arrow function
function CurvedArrow(context, index) {
  this._context = context;
  this._index = index;
}
CurvedArrow.prototype = {
  areaStart: function() {
    this._line = 0;
  },
  areaEnd: function() {
    this._line = NaN;
  },
  lineStart: function() {
    this._point = 0;
  },
  lineEnd: function() {
    if (this._line || (this._line !== 0 && this._point === 1)) {
      this._context.closePath();
    }
    this._line = 1 - this._line;
  },
  point: function(x, y) {
    x = +x, y = +y; // jshint ignore:line
    switch (this._point) {
      case 0:
        this._point = 1;
        this._p1x = x;
        this._p1y = y;
        break;
      case 1:
        this._point = 2; // jshint ignore:line
      default:
        var p1x = this._p1x,
          p1y = this._p1y,
          p2x = x,
          p2y = y,
          dx = p2x - p1x,
          dy = p2y - p1y,
          px = dy,
          py = -dx,
          pr = Math.sqrt(px * px + py * py),
          nx = px / pr,
          ny = py / pr,
          dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy),
          wx = dx / dr,
          wy = dy / dr,
          ahx = wx * ah,
          ahy = wy * ah,
          awx = nx * ar2,
          awy = ny * ar2,
          phx = nx * w2,
          phy = ny * w2,

          //Curve figures
          alpha = Math.floor((this._index - 1) / 2),
          direction = p1y < p2y ? -1 : 1,
          height = (baseHeight + alpha * 3 * ar2) * direction,


          //             r5
          //r7         r6|\
          // ------------  \
          // ____________  /r4
          //r1         r2|/
          //             r3

          r1x = p1x - phx,
          r1y = p1y - phy,
          r2x = p2x - phx - ahx,
          r2y = p2y - phy - ahy,
          r3x = p2x - awx - ahx,
          r3y = p2y - awy - ahy,
          r4x = p2x,
          r4y = p2y,
          r5x = p2x + awx - ahx,
          r5y = p2y + awy - ahy,
          r6x = p2x + phx - ahx,
          r6y = p2y + phy - ahy,
          r7x = p1x + phx,
          r7y = p1y + phy,
          //Curve 1
          c1mx = (r2x + r1x) / 2,
          c1my = (r2y + r1y) / 2,
          m1b = (c1mx - r1x) / (r1y - c1my),
          den1 = Math.sqrt(1 + Math.pow(m1b, 2)),
          mp1x = c1mx + height * (1 / den1),
          mp1y = c1my + height * (m1b / den1),
          //Curve 2
          c2mx = (r7x + r6x) / 2,
          c2my = (r7y + r6y) / 2,
          m2b = (c2mx - r6x) / (r6y - c2my),
          den2 = Math.sqrt(1 + Math.pow(m2b, 2)),
          mp2x = c2mx + height * (1 / den2),
          mp2y = c2my + height * (m2b / den2);

        this._context.moveTo(r1x, r1y);
        this._context.quadraticCurveTo(mp1x, mp1y, r2x, r2y);
        this._context.lineTo(r3x, r3y);
        this._context.lineTo(r4x, r4y);
        this._context.lineTo(r5x, r5y);
        this._context.lineTo(r6x, r6y);
        this._context.quadraticCurveTo(mp2x, mp2y, r7x, r7y);

        break;
    }
  }
};
var w = 600,
  h = 220;
var t0 = Date.now();

var points = [{
  R: 100,
  r: 3,
  speed: 2,
  phi0: 190
}];
var path = d3.line()
  .curve(function(ctx) {
    return new CurvedArrow(ctx, 1);
  });

var svg = d3.select("svg");
var container = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + w / 2 + "," + h / 2 + ")")

container.selectAll("g.planet").data(points).enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "planet").each(function(d, i) {
    d3.select(this).append("circle").attr("r", d.r).attr("cx", d.R)
      .attr("cy", 0).attr("class", "planet");
  });
container.append("path");
var planet = d3.select('.planet circle');

d3.timer(function() {
  var delta = (Date.now() - t0);
  planet.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "rotate(" + d.phi0 + delta * d.speed / 50 + ")";
  });

  var g = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
  g.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", planet.attr('transform'));
  var matrix = g.transform.baseVal.consolidate().matrix;
  svg.selectAll("path").attr('d', function(d) {
    return path([
      [0, 0],
      [matrix.a * 100, matrix.b * 100]
    ])
  });
});
```

```css
path {
  stroke: #11a;
  fill: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="220"></svg>
```

Comment: Wouldn't [something like this (using a marker)](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292) be a lot easier?

Comment: I guess using a marker with something like `orient=auto` would be definitely simpler than drawing / rotating the head but I don't know how when rendering on a `canvas` like you. On a svg element see http://bl.ocks.org/tomgp/d59de83f771ca2b6f1d4 for example if you didn't see it (not mine).

Comment: @Mark markers just look bad, they are more difficult to customize IMO. When highlighting they won't get a border around them correctly like this will. They also won't work when I apply a gradient to the path.

Comment: @Andrew, good reasons.  How about something like calculate the line between the curve midpoint and end, and then set your `r4` point to be line segment distance + N  along that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing what @Mark suggested in the comments, I calculate the point that is the height of the curve away along the normal midway between the two points, then calculate the unit vectors from the start point to  the mid point and again from the midpoint to the end. I can then use those to get all the required points.

```js
var arrowRadius = 6,
  arrowPointRadius = arrowRadius * 2,
  arrowPointHeight = arrowRadius * 3,
  baseHeight = 30;

// Arrow function
function CurvedArrow(context, index) {
  this._context = context;
  this._index = index;
}
CurvedArrow.prototype = {
  areaStart: function() {
    this._line = 0;
  },
  areaEnd: function() {
    this._line = NaN;
  },
  lineStart: function() {
    this._point = 0;
  },
  lineEnd: function() {
    if (this._line || (this._line !== 0 && this._point === 1)) {
      this._context.closePath();
    }
    this._line = 1 - this._line;
  },
  point: function(x, y) {
    x = +x, y = +y; // jshint ignore:line
    switch (this._point) {
      case 0:
        this._point = 1;
        this._p1x = x;
        this._p1y = y;
        break;
      case 1:
        this._point = 2; // jshint ignore:line
      default:
        var p1x = this._p1x,
          p1y = this._p1y,
          p2x = x,
          p2y = y,

          //Curve figures

          //             mp1
          //              |
          //              | height
          //              |
          // p1 ----------------------- p2
          //
          alpha = Math.floor((this._index - 1) / 2),
          direction = p1y < p2y ? -1 : 1,
          height = (baseHeight + alpha * 3 * arrowPointRadius) * direction,
          c1mx = (p2x + p1x) / 2,
          c1my = (p2y + p1y) / 2,
          m1b = (c1mx - p1x) / (p1y - c1my),
          den1 = Math.sqrt(1 + Math.pow(m1b, 2)),
          // Perpendicular point from the midpoint.
          mp1x = c1mx + height * (1 / den1),
          mp1y = c1my + height * (m1b / den1),

          // Arrow figures
          dx = p2x - mp1x,
          dy = p2y - mp1y,
          dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy),
          // Normal unit vectors
          nx = dy / dr,
          wy = nx,
          wx = dx / dr,
          ny = -wx,
          ahx = wx * arrowPointHeight,
          ahy = wy * arrowPointHeight,
          awx = nx * arrowPointRadius,
          awy = ny * arrowPointRadius,
          phx = nx * arrowRadius,
          phy = ny * arrowRadius,

          // Start arrow offset.
          sdx = mp1x - p1x,
          sdy = mp1y - p1y,
          spr = Math.sqrt(sdy * sdy + sdx * sdx),
          snx = sdy / spr,
          sny = -sdx / spr,
          sphx = snx * arrowRadius,
          sphy = sny * arrowRadius,

          //             r5
          //r7         r6|\
          // ------------  \
          // ____________  /r4
          //r1         r2|/
          //             r3

          r1x = p1x - sphx,
          r1y = p1y - sphy,
          r2x = p2x - phx - ahx,
          r2y = p2y - phy - ahy,
          r3x = p2x - awx - ahx,
          r3y = p2y - awy - ahy,
          r4x = p2x,
          r4y = p2y,
          r5x = p2x + awx - ahx,
          r5y = p2y + awy - ahy,
          r6x = p2x + phx - ahx,
          r6y = p2y + phy - ahy,
          r7x = p1x + sphx,
          r7y = p1y + sphy,
          mpc1x = mp1x - phx,
          mpc1y = mp1y - phy,
          mpc2x = mp1x + phx,
          mpc2y = mp1y + phy;

        this._context.moveTo(r1x, r1y);
        this._context.quadraticCurveTo(mpc1x, mpc1y, r2x, r2y);
        this._context.lineTo(r3x, r3y);
        this._context.lineTo(r4x, r4y);
        this._context.lineTo(r5x, r5y);
        this._context.lineTo(r6x, r6y);
        this._context.quadraticCurveTo(mpc2x, mpc2y, r7x, r7y);
        this._context.closePath();

        break;
    }
  }
};

var w = 600,
  h = 220;
var t0 = Date.now();

var points = [{
  R: 100,
  r: 3,
  speed: 2,
  phi0: 190
}];
var path = d3.line()
  .curve(function(ctx) {
    return new CurvedArrow(ctx, 1);
  });

var svg = d3.select("svg");
var container = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + w / 2 + "," + h / 2 + ")")

container.selectAll("g.planet").data(points).enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "planet").each(function(d, i) {
    d3.select(this).append("circle").attr("r", d.r).attr("cx", d.R)
      .attr("cy", 0).attr("class", "planet");
  });
container.append("path");
var planet = d3.select('.planet circle');

d3.timer(function() {
  var delta = (Date.now() - t0);
  planet.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "rotate(" + d.phi0 + delta * d.speed / 50 + ")";
  });

  var g = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
  g.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", planet.attr('transform'));
  var matrix = g.transform.baseVal.consolidate().matrix;
  svg.selectAll("path").attr('d', function(d) {
    return path([
      [0, 0],
      [matrix.a * 100, matrix.b * 100]
    ])
  });
});
```

```css
path {
  stroke: #11a;
  fill: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="220"></svg>
```

Comment: Very cool.  I was working on the same [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/eG1dtD1MHBo3vyTdgcKN?p=preview), you beat me to it :)